# Trouble linking results from 2 CursorLoaders

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I am using the contact intent to get a contact ID and I am then using a CursorLoader to firstly get the following columns

ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID

Then I will use the PHOTO_ID in a second CursorLoader to get the Photo Blob.

I will then use information from both CursorLoaders results to populate a GridView.

I need to store the data returned form the first CursorLoader and combine it with the Photo blob from the second CursorLoader. The id returned from the contact selection seemed the perfect key for a small map.

This works fine on the assumption that a single contact will be selected. I will have two versions of the app though and the other version will allow up to three contacts (using a custom ListView rather than the intent).

I thought that I could return the same _ID column in both CursorLoaders and use that as a common key, but strangely, because the URI for each CursorLoader is different so is the value of the _ID column...

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? I need to link the results from the two CursorLoaders together somehow...﻿

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I actually think that CursorJoiner is more appropriate for my case but without your help I didn't know it existed!

Comment: hmm what will you do with CursorJoiner? it cannot be passed to CursorAdapter but CursorWrapper can be

Comment: You're right. I investigated further and, as you say, the CursorJoiner wasn't an object that could be passed into a CursorAdapter. MergeCursor allows me to combine two cursors into one object and MErgeCursor can be passed into a CursorLoader.

Comment: no no no, MergeCursor "adds" cursors (if you have two Cursors with 5 rows each the result will have 10 rows) what you need is CursorWrapper